# Use axios GET as axios POST in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, lambda, axios

A friend has an API with a `GET`. 
I would like to know if I can send data to a lambda with a `get`, as if I were using a simple `POST`.
I have this

```
await axios.post(
  ' ENDPOINT_API',
  {
    resultat_net_N1:`${resultat_net_N1_form}, ${resultat_net_N1}, ${resultat_net_N1_form_1}, ${resultat_net_N1_1}`,
    resultat_net_N: `${resultat_net_N_form}, ${resultat_net_N}, ${resultat_net_N_form_1}, ${resultat_net_N_1}`,
    },
 );
```

I’d like a `GET` that behaves like this piece of code. I don't know if it's possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're passing data, you can only pass it in a `GET` request as query parameters. For example, `/ENDPOINT_API?param_1=some%20value&param_2=some%20other%20value`

Comment: I admit I don’t understand too much, but at least I know what I have to look for, thank you @Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are workarounds, but they **aren't suggested**, POST SHOULD BE TO POST, and GET SHOULD BE TO GET

```
 const res = await axios.get("/ENDPOINT_API", 
             { data: {
                   resultat_net_N1: resultat_net_N1 } 
             }
    )
```

**I suggest sending them as params**

```
 const res = await axios.get("/ENDPOINT_API", 
                 { params: {
                       resultat_net_N1: resultat_net_N1 } 
                 }
        )
```

Comment: But how do I get params in my lambda AWS? No matter what I try to do, can’t display params content in my lambda. Initially, i have this lambda code. But if i'm just trying to console.log(event.params), it's not working.                                                                       const params = {
        Item: {
            resultat_net_N: event.resultat_net_N,
            resultat_net_N1: event.resultat_net_N1,
        },
            TableName: "serverlessApp"
    };                                      (If I ask too much help, don’t hesitate to stop me, I will continue alone)

Comment: _Express way(nodejs) =>
if you use the second method you would find them at req.params
FOR LAMBDA HMM, **can you try**
event.pathParameters or
event.queryStringParameters
TELL ME IF IT WORKED

Comment: I think I’m doing something wrong. When I use req.params, the lambda can’t find req. And when I use the other two (in my lambda function), I get undefined

Comment: try `{yourURL}?name=castille&category=greatGuy&markAnswer=solutionAnswer`
And console.log  event.pathParameters or event.queryStringParameters   are they still undefined ? 
_req.params works in other platforms, doesn't work in lambda it was just an example_

Comment: remove the params object, just do a get at that url

Comment: i'm sorry for my stupid question (i'm really new with javascript and axios), but i need to do that in my javascript code? Like await axios.get{"myURL"}?name=castille&category=greatGuy&markAnswer=solutionAnswer
 ?  because i have errors with that

Comment: your lambda has a link right?  lets say its 'yyy.com' now do a       axios.get('yyy.com'?name=castille&category=greatGuy)    and console.log  event.pathParameters and event.queryStringParameters
**replace yyy.com with your url**

Comment: yes i have a link but I end up with "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression". I’m not gonna embarrass you all day. It’s not working because I had to screw up somewhere, but I have solid leads thanks to you, and I thank you

Comment: Yep i'm doing that right now, i just looked with a friend, the problem is in my lambda, your code is good. Thx

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the use case you are sending the data. The Get method is exposing the data as query parameters and as the name suggest it is used for getting data from the API. POST method is not exposing the data like get and is used for sending data to the API in its request body. If you try to send sensitive data it is really not recommended to use get. You can find basic difference between the http methods and their usage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)